# Integration by Parts with Laplacian over a Manifold

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, laplacian

I am studying a text on differential geometry where it states during a proof that integration by parts is used to prove the following integral over a closed manifold:

$$
\begin{split}
 &\int_M -\Delta u \log u \: dV=  \int_M \frac{|\nabla u|^2}{u} \: dV\\
\end{split}
$$

I am not sure what detail I am missing here, because if we apply the formula we get a mess as the integral of the log gives a messy term which does not take us closer to the result.  If I try swapping the order of the product and then doing the integration by parts, I just get $0$ since the integral of the Laplacian of a function over a closed manifold vanishes.

Comment: As a sanity check, it's obvious on the flat torus. I believe it's a matter of how you define $\nabla$ and $\Delta$.

Comment: It says in the proof somewhere that they are taking the integral of $\Delta u$ to vanish on a closed manifold, so how can I define $\nabla$ to get the result?

Comment: By flat torus I mean $[0, 1]^n$ with periodic boundary condition.

Comment: I don't immediately see why that would be obvious, sorry, is there some detail I'm missing in my definition of $\nabla$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following general identity holds on any Riemannian manifold, where $f$ and $X$ are a differentiable function and vector field, respectively:

$\nabla \cdot (fX) = \nabla f \cdot X + f \nabla \cdot X; \tag 1$

this may be easily verified by working in a local coordinate system; if we set

$f = \ln u \tag 2$

and

$X = \nabla u \tag 3$

then *via* (1) we have

$\nabla \cdot (\ln u \nabla u) = \nabla \ln u \cdot \nabla u + \ln u \nabla^2 u; \tag 4$

we have

$\nabla \ln u = \dfrac{\nabla u}{u}, \tag 5$

whence

$\nabla \ln u \cdot \nabla u = \dfrac{\nabla u \cdot \nabla u}{u} = \dfrac{\vert \nabla u \vert^2}{u}; \tag 6$

combining (4) and (6) yields

$\nabla \cdot (\ln u \nabla u) = \dfrac{\vert \nabla u \vert^2}{u} + \ln u \nabla^2 u; \tag 7$

if $M$ has a boundary $\partial M$ then by the divergence theorem

$\displaystyle \int_{\partial M} \ln u \nabla u \; dS =  \int_M \nabla \cdot (\ln u \nabla u) \; dV$
$= \displaystyle \int_M \left (\dfrac{\vert \nabla u \vert^2}{u} + \ln u \nabla^2 u \right ) \; dV = \int_M \dfrac{\vert \nabla u \vert^2}{u} \; dV + \int_M \ln u \nabla^2 u\; dV, \tag 8$

where of course we make the necessary assumptions on $u$ and $M$ so that these integrals are all well-defined.  In the event that

$\partial M = \emptyset, \tag 9$

then (8) reduces to

$\displaystyle \int_M \dfrac{\vert \nabla u \vert^2}{u} \; dV = - \int_M \ln u \nabla^2u \; dV, \tag{10}$

$OE\Delta$.

Comment: Can I just double-check why it's reasonable to assume the boundary is the empty set for a closed Riemannian manifold?  Is this a general result or corollary from manifold theory?

Comment: When they say "closed manifold", they mean exactly that; compact and no boundary. It is old-fashioned terminology.

Comment: @Tom:  Guiseppe Negro's comment says it right!